# Use sbt settingKey in function call

Tags: scala, sbt

We have a `build.sbt` file like this, which is working fine:

```
name := "Foo"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

def aws(module: String): ModuleID = "com.amazonaws" % module % "1.11.250"

lazy val Core = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      aws("aws-java-sdk-s3"),
      aws("aws-java-sdk-dynamodb"),
    )
  )
```

Basically, the project has a few AWS SDK library dependencies and we want to avoid typing the `groupID` (e.g. "com.amazonaws") and the `revision` (e.g. "1.11.250") multiple times and that's why we have this line:

```
def aws(module: String): ModuleID = "com.amazonaws" % module % "1.11.250"
```

However, since we have many repos like this and we want to move this definition to a custom `sbt-plugin`. To begin with, we try this:

```
name := "Foo"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

val awsVersion = settingKey[String]("The version of aws SDK used for building.") // line 5
def aws(module: String): ModuleID = "com.amazonaws" % module % awsVersion.value // line 6

awsVersion := "1.11.250"

lazy val Core = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      aws("aws-java-sdk-s3"),
      aws("aws-java-sdk-dynamodb"),
    )
  )
```

However, line 6 is producing an error:

> error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.

The idea is that we'll move line 5 and 6 above to our plugin eventually so that we can use it like this:

```
name := "Foo"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
awsVersion := "1.11.250"

lazy val Core = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      aws("aws-java-sdk-s3"),
      aws("aws-java-sdk-dynamodb"),
    )
  )
```

Any solution or work around for the error above?

---

We've also tried this:

```
def aws(module: String, version: String): ModuleID = "com.amazonaws" % module % version
```

... which is then used like this:

```
awsVersion := "1.11.250"

lazy val Core = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      aws("aws-java-sdk-s3", awsVersion.value),
      aws("aws-java-sdk-dynamodb", awsVersion.value),
    )
  )
```

That works fine though a bit annoying to use and it defeats the purpose of using a `settingKey` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `setting` or `task` values in locally defined methods like `aws`. The values can be used only within other `setting` or `task` definitions, ie the error message `such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.`

This is what you could do.

Create `AutoPlugin` in `project` folder.

```
import sbt.{AutoPlugin, Def, ModuleID, settingKey}
import sbt.PluginTrigger.AllRequirements
import sbt._

object AwsPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger = AllRequirements

  type GetAWS = String => ModuleID

  object autoImport {
    val awsVersion =
      settingKey[String]("The version of aws SDK used for building.")
    val awsLibrary = settingKey[GetAWS]("Builds given AWS library")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    awsLibrary := { id =>
      "com.amazonaws" % id % awsVersion.value
    }
  )
}
```

Use it in this way in `build.sbt`

```
awsVersion in ThisBuild := "1.11.250"

lazy val Core = project
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      awsLibrary.value("aws-java-sdk-s3"),
      awsLibrary.value("aws-java-sdk-dynamodb"),
    )
  )
```